# put duplicated rows in different data.frame(s)

Tags: r, duplicates

Let

```
x=c(1,2,2,3,4,1)
y=c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
df=data.frame(x,y)



 df
      x y
    1 1 A
    2 2 B
    3 2 C
    4 3 D
    5 4 E
    6 1 F
```

How can I put duplicate rows in this data frame in different data frames
like this :

```
df1
     x y
     1 A
     1 F

df2
     x y
     2 B
     2 C
```

Thank you for help

Comment: check `?split` `split(df, f= df$x)`

Comment: and you will have to remove the data frames with non duplicated rows later

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar could you please help with this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149683/matrix-division-in-several-dataframes-so-that-each-dataframe-contain-duplicate-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `split`

```
split(df, f = df$x)
```

`f = df$x` is used to specify the grouping column
check `?split` for more details

to remove the non duplicated rows you could use

```
mylist = split(df, f = df$x)[df$x[duplicated(df$x)]]
names(mylist) = c('df1', 'df2') 
list2env(mylist,envir=.GlobalEnv) # to separate the data frames
```