# Matrix division in several dataframes so that each dataframe contain duplicate rows

Tags: r

I have a data matrix

```
dataA <- matrix(c(0.74, 1.00,0.56, 0.74, 1.00,0.56, 0.74, 1.00, 0.56,0.39, 0.79, 0.35, 0.39, 0.79, 0.35),  ncol=3, nrow=3)
```

that looks like:

```
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]       
[1,] 0.74   1.00   0.56     
[2,] 0.74   1.00   0.56     
[3,] 0.74   1.00   0.56     
[4,] 0.39   0.79   0.35     
[5,] 0.39   0.79   0.35
```

and what I need to get is two data frames that will look like :

Group1

```
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   
1     0.74   1.00   0.56     
2     0.74   1.00   0.56     
3     0.74   1.00   0.56
```

Group2

```
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
 4    0.39   0.79   0.35     
 5    0.39   0.79   0.35
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Imo ganging is my dataframe name so I tried                                         split(ganging, f = ganging[,1])[ganging[,1][duplicated(ganging[,1])]]

Comment: Add what you tried to the body of your question rather than in the comments. Also include a toy example of your data.frame in your question by pasting the output of `dput(ganging)` or `dput(head(ganging, 20))` if the dataset is large.

Comment: @Imo sorry I am new in R. I edited my Question, hope makes sense now

Comment: The initial matrix in your question does not match `dataA <- ...`. you could use `dataA <- matrix(c(rep(c(0.74, 1.00,0.56), 3), rep(c(0.39, 0.79, 0.35), 2)), 5, byrow=TRUE) `.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this. Use `apply` and `paste` to get vectors of your row elements as a single string per row. Feed this to `split` as well as the number of rows of your matrix in order to break up the matrix rows by duplicates. Then feed the list of grouped rows that `split` outputs to `lapply` to perform the subsetting of dataA.

```
myMatList <- lapply(split(seq_len(nrow(dataA)),
                          apply(dataA, 1, paste, collapse=" ")),
                    function(x) dataA[x,])
```

which returns

```
myMatList

$`0.39 0.79 0.35`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.39 0.79 0.35
[2,] 0.39 0.79 0.35

$`0.74 1 0.56`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.74    1 0.56
[2,] 0.74    1 0.56
[3,] 0.74    1 0.56
```

To add names, you can paste "Group" to the index of list items like this.

```
names(myMatList) <- paste0("Group", seq_along(myMatList))
```

If it is important to maintain the order of the matrix in the names, you can use `match`

```
# use index from match() as argument to paste0
names(myMatList) <- paste0("Group", match(names(myMatList),
                                          unique(apply(dataA, 1, paste, collapse=" "))))
```

where `unique(apply(dataA, 1, paste, collapse=" ")))` contains the table of of the unique rows of the matrix in it original order.

**data**

```
dataA <- matrix(c(rep(c(0.74, 1.00,0.56), 3), rep(c(0.39, 0.79, 0.35), 2)), 5, byrow=TRUE)
```

Comment: @Imo Thanks so much for your help!!! it worked perfectly. How can I give these groups my own names like Group1 and Group2? I have a huge dataset and here I gave just a small portion.